# Is it possible to implement such UI structure in react-admin?

Tags: tree, react-admin

[react-admin tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ9lH.pngh)

A tree will be huge. Each tab will contain data grid or form based on selected tree item.

Any ideas?

Comment: The react-admin demo example shows how you can represent a filter as tabs (see https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/e2697fa2c20293d4056d94b7529824b70713ef25/examples/demo/src/orders/OrderList.js#L51-L162). I think the same idea can be used to represent a filter as a tree.